# QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMARIADB QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5, qtableview, qsqldatabase

I wanna make a MySQL database mapping to QTableView but i got this error:
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMARIADB QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7

My code is:

```
from mysql.connector import connect, Error
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView

class Ui_self(QMainWindow):
    connection = connect(host="",
                         user='',
                         password='',
                         database="",
                         charset='utf8')

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("MySQL Table View")
        self.resize(800, 600)
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
        db.setHostName("")
        db.setDatabaseName("")
        db.setUserName('')
        db.setPassword('')
        db.open()
        self.setupUi()
        self.show()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.model = QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable('students')
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        self.model.select()
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 801, 561))
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(self)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(self)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi()
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_self()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have already tried to move qsqlmysql.dll and libmysql.dll in the needs paths by guides but it doesn't helps me

Python 3.9.13 64-bit
Windows 10
PyQt ver. 5.15.4